# Dynamic custom Angular directive/$compile not working with .innerHTML()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, innerhtml

I have a timer application. When the countdown timer gets to a certain number, the timer will stop and a `div` tag will be created within another `div` tag using `.innerHTML()`. This `div` tag contains a custom Angular directive named `dynamic`. This directive should `$compile` a template with a `button` tag that calls a function within the Angular controller `timerControl` when clicked.

***What currently happens is the timer runs up and fires off the following `if` statement in my `timerControl` controller...***

```
if(time_until_break-- < 0){  
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<div dynamic></div>'
}
```

***It should run through the following directive and append a `button` to the html per instruction of the following...***

```
grindModule.directive("dynamic", function($compile){
return{
    link: function(scope, element){
        var template = "<button ng-click='timerControl.resetTimer()'>Keep Working</button>";
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.append(content);
    }
}
```

});

***But instead it only append the following to the HTML...***

```
<div dynamic></div>
```

What gives?

I can't seem to find anything on Stack Overflow that tells you how to link an `HTML` element to the `$scope` after or before appending said element to the `DOM` using `.innerHTML()`.

Comment: You need to use the `$compile` service to instantiate a copy of the `dynamic` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add markup manually, like

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<div dynamic></div>'
```

you are bypassing all AngularJS code. You should do it rather as this:

```
angular.element("#test").html('<div dynamic></div>');
```

Comment: This seems like good advice. I am getting the same result though.

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't actually need a full blown directive. Instead, I just wrote something like this. `angular.element('#test').html('<button id="back_to_work" ng-click="timerControl.resetTimer()"></button>)
                $compile( angular.element('#back_to_work') )($scope)`; I used your suggestion though. Thanks for whipping my code into shape!